# Would it be possible to derive more than one differential equation from one solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the general solution

$y = C_{1}e^{-x} + C_{2}e^{x} + x$

I found one differential equation from this solution which is $y'' - y = -x$.

But are there other differential equations we can get from this solution? If yes, is there a procedure we can follow for any general solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You could create an infinite amount of ODE's given a curve. For example, add $y'''$ to your ODE (you'd have to change your RHS as well of course) and you'd have a different one.

Comment: @Eli : But then the given family would no longer be the *general* solution. Up to multiplication with constant factors, this is indeed the only equation for this family with explicit highest-order term. $\exp(y'')=\exp(y-x)$ would be an implicit equation.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. If you also set initial values for all derivatives except the higher order one, then you can see you have a unique solution thanks to Cauchy-Lipshitz theorem. But maybe I didn't understand the question?